# Different data structures & Complexities

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, reference, complexity-theory

I know this **[wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)** exists which has different data structures.

I want to know if there is a place where I can get the complexities (for insert, delete, update etc.) in a neat table format (for reference).

Answer (score 0):

The page that you linked to in your question has a list of many data structures. Each of them a page that details the specific data structures. I know you want the table of comparisons in a ready made format but since it does not appear to exist then it might be something that you can put together easily by browsing through the various pages. For instance the comparison of the various algorithms in the array is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Efficiency_comparison_with_other_data_structures), and for the b-tree [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). So it may require some work to compile it all into a simple reference. Hmmm...maybe there is a blog post in the making.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to avoid. but who know it might be fun. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is on Wikipedia: [Worst-case analysis of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure#Asymptotic_amortized_worst-case_analysis)

```
+----------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
|                      |  Insert  |   Delete   |  Search  | Space Usage  |
+----------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
| Unsorted array       | O(1)     | O(1)       | O(n)     | O(n)         |
| Value-indexed array  | O(1)     | O(1)       | O(1)     | O(n)         |
| Sorted array         | O(n)     | O(n)       | O(log n) | O(n)         |
| Unsorted linked list | O(1)*    | O(1)*      | O(n)     | O(n)         |
| Sorted linked list   | O(n)*    | O(1)*      | O(n)     | O(n)         |
| Balanced binary tree | O(log n) | O(log n)   | O(log n) | O(n)         |
| Heap                 | O(log n) | O(log n)** | O(n)     | O(n)         |
| Hash table           | O(1)     | O(1)       | O(1)     | O(n)         |
+----------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+

 * The cost to add or delete an element into a known location in the list
   (i.e. if you have an iterator to the location) is O(1).
   If you don't know the location, then you need to traverse the list to the location of deletion/insertion, which takes O(n) time. 
** The deletion cost is O(log n) for the minimum or maximum, O(n) for an arbitrary element.
```